# XCB get events of all windows X.Org

Tags: c, linux, event-handling, x11, xcb

I'm currently working on a latency test for Linux. For minimizing side effects I try to write a C-program which directly accesses the X-Server with XCB.
Because not having any experience in C, but only in Java, nor in XCB, I ran into a few difficulties.

Everything the application should do is to show a white frame and if the button of the mouse is pressed at any time (outside the window), it should change to black in an instant.
The test-application doesn't have to be beautiful or safe in any way but only react fast. It is just used for this one test (please don't judge my crappy style ;-) ).

The mouse can not be in the same window, because there is another independent application which also needs to process the event (the one measuring the latency).

---

After reading [the XCB tutorial](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/) I have modified the sample code to open a window and log the mouse clicks inside the window:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

main ()
{
    /* Open the connection to the X server */
    xcb_connection_t *connection = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

    /* Get the first screen */
    xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (connection)).data;

    /* Create black (foreground) graphic context */
    xcb_drawable_t  window;
    uint32_t        mask;
    uint32_t        values[2];

    /* Create a window */
    window = xcb_generate_id (connection);

    mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
    values[0] = screen->white_pixel;
    values[1] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS;

    xcb_create_window (connection, XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT, window, screen->root, 0, 0, 500, 500, 10, XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, screen->root_visual, mask, values );

    /* Map the window on the screen and flush*/
    xcb_map_window (connection, window);
    xcb_flush (connection);

    /* Get XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS event */
    xcb_generic_event_t *event;
    while ((event = xcb_wait_for_event (connection))) {
        switch (event ->response_type & ~0x80) {
        case XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS:
            printf("Button pressed!\n");
            break;
        default: 
            /* Unknown event type */
            printf("Unknown event!\n");
            break;
        }
        /* free (event); */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For getting the events of all windows, I guess I have to change the `window` variable to the root window. But anything I try produces a Segmentation Fault, or simply does not work.

Maybe a child of root (my application) does not have enough rights for getting events of it's parent? But how is `xwininfo -root` working then?
Best attempt:

```c
xcb_connection_t *connection = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);
xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (connection)).data;
xcb_drawable_t window = screen->root; /* !!! */
uint32_t mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
uint32_t values[2];
values[0] = screen->white_pixel;
values[1] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS;
xcb_change_window_attributes (connection, window, mask, values); /* !!! */
xcb_map_window (connection, window);
xcb_flush (connection);
```

---

**How do I have to change the above code to react to all BUTTON_PRESS events on the whole X.Org-Server?**

Comment: I think you can access /dev/input/* directly (using `ioctl`) to get that info for every window if you have `root` access.  I was able to open an `evevt*` file, and read keyboard presses.  [Possibly helpful reference for mouse](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/166412-intercepting-usb-traffic-generated-mouse.html)

Comment: I think you have to use the Xinput2 extension. That is what `xinput --test-xi2 --root` does, but for some reason only one instance of `xinput` may be running. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39363761/4414935) help?

Answer (score 12):

So if you want to capture all the buttons events, I have just a solution but I don't know if this could fit your needs.

Its like a little window manager here is 4 files:

- simple_window_manager.c
- events.c
- events.h
- Makefile

*simple_window_manager.c*

```
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_event.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_aux.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "events.h"

xcb_connection_t * connection;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  xcb_screen_t      *screen;

  /*open connection and check for error*/
  connection = xcb_connect( NULL, NULL);

  printf("launch connection");

    if (xcb_connection_has_error(connection))
  {
    perror("cannot open display\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /*get first screen*/
  screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(connection)).data;

  /*define the application as window manager*/
    const uint32_t select_input_val[] =
    {
        XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT | XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY
        | XCB_EVENT_MASK_ENTER_WINDOW | XCB_EVENT_MASK_LEAVE_WINDOW
        | XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY | XCB_EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE
        | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE
        | XCB_EVENT_MASK_FOCUS_CHANGE
    };
    xcb_change_window_attributes(connection,
                                 screen->root,
                                 XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK, select_input_val);
    /* Need to xcb_flush to validate error handler */
  xcb_aux_sync(connection);

    if (xcb_poll_for_event(connection) != NULL)
    {
        perror("another window manager is already running");
        exit(1);
    };

  /*flush all request*/
  xcb_flush(connection);

  xcb_generic_event_t *the_events;
  int done; 

    /*enter the main loop*/
  done = 0;
  while (!done && (the_events = xcb_wait_for_event(connection)))
  {
    switch(the_events->response_type)
    {
      /*(re)draw the window*/
      case XCB_EXPOSE:
        printf ("EXPOSE\n");
        break;
      /*exit on keypress*/
      case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
        done = 1;
        break;
      default:
        event_management(the_events);
        printf("The events = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(the_events->response_type));
    }
    free(the_events);
  }
  /*close connection to server*/
  xcb_disconnect(connection);
  return 0;
}
```

*events.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_util.h>
#include "events.h"


static void button_press_management(xcb_button_press_event_t * event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void button_release_management(xcb_button_release_event_t * event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void configure_request_management(xcb_configure_request_event_t * event)
{
    uint16_t config_win_mask = 0;
  uint32_t config_win_vals[7];
  unsigned short i = 0;

if(event->value_mask & XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_X)
    {
        config_win_mask |= XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_X;
        config_win_vals[i++] = 300;
        printf(" XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_X\n");
    }
    if(event->value_mask & XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_Y)
    {
        config_win_mask |= XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_Y;
        config_win_vals[i++] = 300;
        printf(" XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_Y\n");
    }
    if(event->value_mask & XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_WIDTH)
    {
        config_win_mask |= XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_WIDTH;
        config_win_vals[i++] = event->width;
        printf(" XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_WIDTH\n");
    }
    if(event->value_mask & XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_HEIGHT)
    {
        config_win_mask |= XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        config_win_vals[i++] = event->height;
        printf("XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_HEIGHT");
    }
    if(event->value_mask & XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_BORDER_WIDTH)
    {
        config_win_mask |= XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_BORDER_WIDTH;
        config_win_vals[i++] = event->border_width;
        printf(" XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_BORDER_WIDTH\n");
    }
    if(event->value_mask & XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_SIBLING)
    {
        config_win_mask |= XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_SIBLING;
        config_win_vals[i++] = event->sibling;
        printf(" XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_SIBLING\n");
    }
    if(event->value_mask & XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_STACK_MODE)
    {
        config_win_mask |= XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_STACK_MODE;
        config_win_vals[i++] = event->stack_mode;
        printf(" XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_STACK_MODE\n");
    }

  xcb_configure_window(connection, event->window, config_win_mask, config_win_vals);
  xcb_flush(connection);
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void client_message_management(xcb_client_message_event_t * event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void expose_management(xcb_expose_event_t *event)
{
        printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void focus_in_management(xcb_focus_in_event_t *event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void key_press_management(xcb_key_press_event_t *event)
{

    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void key_release_management(xcb_key_release_event_t *event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void motion_notify_management(xcb_motion_notify_event_t * event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void map_request_management(xcb_map_request_event_t * event)
{
  xcb_map_window(connection, event->window);
  xcb_flush(connection);
  xcb_grab_button(connection,0, event->window,XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_NONE, XCB_NONE, XCB_BUTTON_INDEX_ANY, XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY);
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void mapping_notify_management(xcb_motion_notify_event_t * event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void reparent_notify_management(xcb_reparent_notify_event_t * event)
{

    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void unmap_notify_management(xcb_unmap_notify_event_t * event)
{

    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void enter_notify_management(xcb_enter_notify_event_t * event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}
static void leave_notify_management(xcb_leave_notify_event_t * event)
{
    printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
}

void event_management(xcb_generic_event_t *event)
{   
    uint8_t response_type = XCB_EVENT_RESPONSE_TYPE(event);

    if(response_type == 0)
        {
      /* This is an error, not a event */
      perror("response_type = 0");
      return;
      }

    switch(response_type)
        {
            case XCB_BUTTON_PRESS:
                button_press_management((void *) event);
                break;
            case XCB_BUTTON_RELEASE:
                button_release_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_CONFIGURE_REQUEST:
                configure_request_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE:
                client_message_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_EXPOSE:
                expose_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_FOCUS_IN:
                focus_in_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
                key_press_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_KEY_RELEASE:
                key_release_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_MAP_REQUEST:
                map_request_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_MAPPING_NOTIFY:
                mapping_notify_management((void *)event);
                break;case XCB_MOTION_NOTIFY:
                motion_notify_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_REPARENT_NOTIFY:
                reparent_notify_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_UNMAP_NOTIFY:
                unmap_notify_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_ENTER_NOTIFY:
                enter_notify_management((void *)event);
                break;
            case XCB_LEAVE_NOTIFY:
                leave_notify_management((void *)event);
                break;
            default:
                printf("event = %s\n",xcb_event_get_label(event->response_type));   
                printf("%d\n",response_type);
                perror("this kind of event is not managed\n");
                break;
        }
}
```

*events.h*

```
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
extern xcb_connection_t * connection;
void event_management(xcb_generic_event_t *);
```

*Makefile*

```
CC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -Wall
EXEC_NAME = simple_window_manager 
INCLUDES = 
LIBS =-lxcb -lxcb-util
OBJ_FILES = simple_window_manager.o events.o
INSTALL_DIR = ./my_exec/

all : $(EXEC_NAME)
clean :
    rm $(EXEC_NAME) $(OBJ_FILES)

$(EXEC_NAME) : $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC_NAME) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

install :
    cp $(EXEC_NAME) $(INSTALL_DIR)$(EXEC_NAME)
```

Copy those 4 files, run

```
Makefile
```

then try this in a shell session (I will explain why after):

```
Xephyr -br -noreset -screen "1024x640" :1&
DISPLAY=:1.0 ./simple_window_manager&
DISPLAY=:1.0 gnome-calculator #for example
```

In order to get all the events to the root window, you have to configure the root window like if your application is a window manager. But it can be only one window manager that is the reason why simple_window_manager cannot be run under gnome or kde for example. You have to use Xephyr for your test.

That is the only way I know to get all the events. I am not an expert, I hope this can help you.

Comment: Wow very deep answer. I think this might be the solution to a problem I'm having. May you please take a look at my topic and see if this solution you posted here fits me? Thank you so much my question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906243/no-error-on-xcb-grab-key-but-event-loop-not-catching-global-hotkey

Comment: The reason I ask is because when I tried your code I keep getting a non-null value for `xcb_poll_for_event` telling me error "another window manager is already running".

Comment: I have tested it just 2 minutes ago to be sure but no everything went fine for me, the compilation and the execution. Did you follow the instruction,s I meen using Xephyr to create a new display ":1" and launch the simple_window_manager on it ?

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I realize now this is not my solution, I'm not needing to createa a new display, I'm just trying to get the events of the current display. :( Thanks for your reply in my other topic Ill reply there as well :)